# Getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' on an empty list

Tags: python

Here's the snippet of my function:

```
def getFriends(screen_name, user_id=0):
    friends = []
    twitter = login()
    if screen_name:
    response = make_twitter_request(twitter.friends.ids, screen_name=screen_name, count=5000)
    else:
    response = make_twitter_request(twitter.friends.ids, user_id=user_id, count=5000)
    friends += response['ids']
    for i in range(10):
    cursor = response['next_cursor']
    if(cursor!=0):
        response = make_twitter_request(twitter.friends.ids, screen_name=screen_name, count=5000)
        friends += response['ids']
        print friends
    return friends
```

I've confirmed that response is not empty and that friends is indeed the empty list, yet when I try to do `friends += response['ids']` I get the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw2.py", line 75, in <module>
    makeGraph('katyperry')
  File "hw2.py", line 67, in makeGraph
    myList = getFriends(None, user_id=user_id)
  File "hw2.py", line 30, in getFriends
    friends += response['ids']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Anyone has any idea why? Is it something really obvious that I"m missing?

Edit: here's the response, I've cut out the list a bit, but this is generally what you get

```
{u'next_cursor_str': u'1319524982440652073', u'previous_cursor': 0, u'ids': [764777174, 201407468, 354264328, 84230267, 19777398, 822447170, 1969597074, 215511591, 1072197655, 93090464, 1895856553, 2148169409, 209708391, 441902035, 32469566, 158314798, 59013314, 90368637, 1205971568, 2218722350, 26334324, 150459410, 188553447, 606580718, 16411682, 404747151, 50127057, 433057142, 387713711, 343649316, 1066545259, 1210138951, 1178700428, 325652049, 265234804, 176538071, 1671978253, 400541768, 111718180, 2320113704, 317262708, 716735610, 2299884229, 2310952307, 278721743, 172989401, 745672010, 289403411, 569259066, 704350131, 380131462, 1353007663, 551726304, 1129951819, 1196832457, 572515555, 1699140998, 238251656, 2183313640, 2271781134, 239867327, 283216570, 2187940812, 213011297, 1876144244, 26968935, 1655642300, 272308935, 1571227472, 325651498, 998220847, 550442329, 1240472737, 24607504, 64080354, 34774807, 211151198, 265495165, 44444328, 2159461650, 186888760, 263960873, 244490281, 1470947208, 431145806, 407064130, 133880286], u'next_cursor': 1319524982440652073, u'previous_cursor_str': u'0'}
```

Comment: `response` is `None`; what does `make_twitter_request()` do?

Comment: make_twitter_request() is a wrapper that makes twitter api calls. It's working as intended, and it does return the correct json response.

Comment: Try to print out the type and contnet of response.

Comment: @Sheng I've done so and added to the original post

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in your post, and add the source of `make_twitter_request` if it's not too long? Thanks.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat: There are *two* locations where you call `make_twitter_request()`; did you test the response in both locations? Which line is line 30 here?

Answer (score 2):

You set `response` with:

```
response = make_twitter_request(twitter.friends.ids, screen_name=screen_name, count=5000)
```

and `make_twitter_request()` returned `None`.

Comment: I have confirmed that it does not return None

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat: The **only way** you can get that exception is by `make_twitter_request()` to return `None`.

Comment: It's puzzling, as you can see, that's the response that I printed out right before the +=.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat you do this `response['ids']` twice in `getFriends`.  Print out `response` before both cases, I'm betting there is some instance where this will be `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`response` must be `None`. `__getitem__` is the Python magic method for overloading `[]` (that is to say, `a[1]` calls `a.__class__.__getitem__(1)`). You're getting this error because you're still using 2.x, if you upgraded to the newer 3.x series (which is incompatible in some minor ways, mostly a cleanup of the language), you get the friendlier `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

There is nothing else on that line that could be causing that error, so unless `make_twitter_request` is returning some funky class that has a weird `__getitem__`, `response` must be `None`.

Comment: That's why I'm asking this question, the response is confirmed to not be None, and in fact is a perfectly valid json object, but yet I'm getting this error. Very puzzling.